# When I use pushViewController I don't get any response

Tags: ios, swift

I try to play a video and I want to switch to a new storyboard afterwards. But for some reason the pushViewController is not doing anything.

I will appreciate any hint to get this running. Thank you all.

View Controller File

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
       
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    
    private func playVideo() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "screen3", ofType: "mp4" ) else {
            debugPrint("video missing")
            return
        }
        
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path) )
        
        playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        playerController.player = player
        playerController.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerController.player?.currentItem )
        
        present(playerController, animated: true ) {
            player.play()
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification ) {
        print("Video finished")
        
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Alternate", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC
                
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: false)
    }
  
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        playVideo()
 
    }
     
}
```

SecondVC

```
    class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        print("alterante")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .link
    }
       
    
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint and check the execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what is happening:

1. You have a `Navigation Controller` which contains `UIViewController`
2. You present the `AVPlayerViewController` **on top of** the `UIViewController and its UINavigationController`
3. When you push the `SecondVC`, it is **over** `UIViewController and its UINavigationController` but **under** `AVPlayerViewController` so you don't see it

Why don't you update your `playerDidFinishPlaying` function to something like this:

```
@objc
func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification ) {
    print("Video finished")
    
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Alternate",
                               bundle: Bundle.main)
        .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC
    
    // Push SecondVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: false)
    
    // Dismiss AVPlayerViewController
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

Does this give you the results you were looking for ?

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stuck for days. Already had the feeling that the former view is covering the new one. But I don't have enough practice so far. Anyway, thanks a lot! Saved my day.